# I want to use a static random number in a non-static class. (Java)

Tags: java, random, static

I am making a Higher or lower game. I need a random number in my game, but the problem is each time that I press the button to guess (The app uses the number from the EditText to compare) the random number changes. So I used a Static, but the problem now is that the function `findViewById` doesn't work anymore since it is not static.

Here is my code:

```
public static void click (View view) {
    double number = Math.ceil(Math.random()* 20);

    EditText textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textIn);

    int givenN = Integer.parseInt(textIn.getText().toString());

    if (number > givenN) {
        System.out.println("Higher");
    } else if (number == givenN){
        System.out.println("Good!");
    } else if (number < givenN) {
        System.out.println("Lower");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: this belong to the oncreate method actually: ***EditText textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textIn);***

Comment: and the click method is a callback so is not static

Comment: isn't that android?! but symbolic-math??

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger remove it!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: @Michael  but I have no idea it is or not  android?? I would rather have done it in one edit!!!! or hoped for the author to do it!!!!!!!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yep, it's definitely Android. The whole `onCreate` method is dead giveaway. That's not particularly relevant to the question, though.

Comment: @Michael sure... every Java programmer should know the details about `onCreate()`, `click()`, `findViewById()`, ... [:-| OO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is each time that I press the button to guess the random
>   number changes.

Right. So you need to change this so it only happens once. Moving this to the 
`onCreate` method seems reasonable enough to me:

```
private double number = -1;

public void click (View view) // Note: no longer static.
{
    EditText textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textIn);
    int givenN = Integer.parseInt(textIn.getText().toString());
    if (number > givenN) {
        System.out.println("Higher");
    } else if (number == givenN){
        System.out.println("Good!");
    } else if (number < givenN) {
        System.out.println("Lower");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    number = Math.ceil(Math.random()* 20);
}
```

Comment: Dear Michael, thank you for your answer. As I am a beginner, I did not know the use of the @Override and onCreate function. Thank you for helping me with this. My app works like a charm.

Comment: @PerbieB You're welcome! You might want to check out [this page which describes the activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the number each time the button is clicked on this line:

```
double number =  Math.ceil(Math.random()* 20);
```

You must remove this line from `click()` and generate this value into `onCreate()` method and save it into a field like that :

```
private double number;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.number =  Math.ceil(Math.random()* 20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want, the problem is that you recalculate the variable 'number' each time you call the click method.

The variable 'number' should be a class property and be calcualted just once or with another function

```
private static double number;    

public void click (View view) {
    EditText textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textIn);
    int givenN = Integer.parseInt(textIn.getText().toString());

    if (number > givenN) {
         System.out.println("Higher");
    } else if (number == givenN){
         System.out.println("Good!");
    } else if (number < givenN) {
         System.out.println("Lower");
    }
}


protected void newNumber() {
    number =  Math.ceil(Math.random()* 20);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    newNumber();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this really adds anything over the answers me and Prim added 10 minutes ago.

Comment: I posted before seeing your answers